# How to deduce the conditions for using the final value theorem from the proof itself?

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, proof-explanation, control-theory

For final value theorem:

> Suppose $X(s)$ is rational and strictly proper, then if $X(s)$ has all
>   poles in the open left half plane and at most one pole at zero, then
>   $$\lim\limits_{t \to \infty} x(t) = \lim\limits_{s \to 0} s X(s)$$

I am trying to reverse engineer the proof and I couldn't figure out how the properties on the poles came into play.

Proof: $\mathcal{L}(\dot x(t)) = sX(s) - x(0) = 
\int\limits_0^\infty \dot x(t) e^{-st}\mathrm{d}t$, take limit on both sides as $s \to 0$, we have $\lim\limits_{s \to 0} s X(s) = \int\limits_0^\infty \dot x(t) \mathrm{d}t + x(0) = \lim\limits_{t \to \infty} x(t)$. End of proof.

It is not obvious to me how the conditions on the poles came into play here.

1. Suppose $X(s)$ had pole of order $\geq 2$ at zero i.e. $X(s) = \dfrac{1}{s^2}$, then it is clear that the left hand side will blow up thus not yielding a finite value. But this does not mean that $\lim\limits_{t \to \infty} x(t) \to \infty$.
2. Suppose $X(s)$ had a pole in the right half plane (i.e. real part of pole $> 0$), then it seems that the proof will still hold.

Can someone explain how one would obtain the conditions on the poles for the final value theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do it by parts.

First assume $ X(s) $ has two or more poles at zero, then $ \underset{s \rightarrow 0}{\lim} sX(s) \rightarrow \infty $. While $ \underset{t \rightarrow \infty}{\lim} x(t) $ can either tend to infinity or to an arbitrary value depending on the initial state.

Second assume $ X(s) $ has at least one pole with positive real part. Then $ \underset{s \rightarrow 0}{\lim} sX(s)$  tends to some constant while $\underset{t \rightarrow \infty}{\lim} x(t) \rightarrow \infty $.

You can verify this two conditions by taking the inverse Laplace transform of $ X(s) $, and verify the conditions for the resulting ODE to converge to $ \underset{s \rightarrow 0}{\lim} sX(s) $.

EDIT: As an addendum, this are the conditions where the equality you used hold.